# Change anchor tag background onclick when href is redirecting link

Tags: jquery, html, css, href

HTML

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Main Page</a></li>               
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'eftrqsthead','action' => 'new'), 'default', true) ?>">EFT Request Head</a></li>              
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'eftrecvhead','action' => 'new'), 'default', true) ?>">EFT Receive Head</a></li>             
    </ul>          
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main_menu a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('tabSelect');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('tabSelect');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#main_menu ul li a:hover, 
#main_menu ul li a.tabSelect{
    background:url(../images/main_menu_bg_hover.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

What I am trying here is to change the background of anchor tag after clicking it.
Problem is if `a href="#"` it is working fine, but if `a href="some link"`, the background is reverting back to normal position.

How can I handle this situation?? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code on jsfiddle.net so we can help you.

Comment: You could try use the `:visited` on the links, see [here for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)

Comment: try using background:url(../images/main_menu_bg_hover.gif) repeat-x !important;

Comment: Infact what happening is when the page redirects to the link, class is again reverting back to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that different css is affecting the element as well. This could be a a:visited rule, or something alike.

The easiest (not per se best) way to fix it might be the use of !important:

```
#main_menu ul li a.tabSelect{
    background:url(../images/main_menu_bg_hover.gif) repeat-x !important;
}
```

The best way would be to use debug tools (e.g. Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools) to see which styling is applied to the element when it is working, and when it is not working as you intend. The differences will lead you to the cause.